# PHP header on an included file

Tags: php, html

I have a typical PHP app structure. Something like this

### index.php

```
include('header.php');

HTML content

include('footer.php');
```

Within header.php there is a check and function call

```
include('loginFunctions.php');

if (!userLoggedIn()){
  loginRedirect();
}
```

loginfunctions.php

```
function loginRedirect(){
  header('location: login.php');
  exit();
}
```

The issue is that if the user was logged in, goes to some page, and then a timer expires where they are logged out, the header redirect loads the login.php page in the header.php page. So the user is stuck on whatever page they were navigating, and now see the login page within the same page. Why does header not redirect the browser? Any other method to do this? I need that function to be common for all pages so that's why it is in header.php

Comment: Quick check, is login.php in the same directory? Also need the code from userLoggedin();

Comment: You can add these rules to your `.htaccess` to throw all available errors. `php_flag display_startup_errors on`
`php_flag display_errors on`
`php_flag html_errors on`

Comment: Every file is in the same directory. There's no errors. It is just that it is loading the login.php file into header.php instead of redirecting the browser.

Comment: Post more code please.

Comment: @tdoakiiii Is anything being output to the browser before the header call? Any text, (even whitespace) sent before header will cause problems.

Comment: I don't know what else you need. userLoggedIn just checks a session variable.

Comment: What does `loginFunctions.php` do? Does it output any content?

Comment: It just has a session_start() and a couple of functions. Nothing ouput on its own.

Comment: does the login.php include the header?

Comment: Yes it does. It is like a regular page that would appear before the index page. I think the issue is that the userLoggedIn is also being run by an AJAX call that happens every 5 seconds. I think that is the issue. Is there a problem when using PHP header(location.. from an AJAX request?

Comment: You seems you are missing essential information in the question, like that it is using ajax

Comment: Yeah seems I forgot about the second call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there was an AJAX request that was also issuing the userLoggedIn function and loading the login page from the AJAX request.

To remedy I return the result as a json echo and process with js.